# Flask FileStorage how get File size

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I need an application that let users upload files to a public path where others can download it, but they are not allowed to upload a file that already exists. To check it faster i need to know the requested file's size and compare with file size of the others already uploaded files.

The problem:

```
file = request.files['file'] #returns FileStorage
```

And in the [docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage.stream) there is no reference to how get the file size. After using `file.save(public_path_to_file)` I can get the file size using `os.stat(public_path_to_file).st_size`. But **before using save()** I have not found a way to get the size of the incomming file.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score -3):

You can do it by importing os.
For example:

```
import os
sizeFile = os.stat('file.txt')
statinfo.st_size
```